boot usb iso-image from grub2
My laptop refuses to boot from a "live" usb stick, but I have grub2 on my HD, so I thought I'd boot the stick from there. In the grub2 console I tried:
set root=(hd0,msdos2)
chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi

but the only result is some cryptic message:
/EndEntire

file path: /ACPI(a.341d0,0)/PCI(0,14)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,22,...,1,1)/File(\efi\boot/File(bootx64.efi)/EndEntire

Any suggestions?

(hdX) depends on drive you boot from. My system where flash drive is sdc or hd2, on reboot it is hd0. So if booting from hd0, then flash drive may be hd1? I often have to experiment and use ls at grub terminal to check drive & partitions to see files.

You might use the ls command to make sure you have the right device.   I would have thought hd0 was your hard drive.
As I used it, the second line would have been chainloader ($root)/efi/Boot/Bootx64.efi  (note that case doesn't matter, and this is perhaps too early in the process.)
I've also done configfile ($root)/grub/grub.cfg inside a submenu block to import the grub menu.
You can also just do the various commands from the usb stick's grub to boot it without using its grub.
I should also inquire: are you sure there is grub on the USB stick?  Are you sure there is an EFI boot setup on the USB?


yes I did ls first to make sure I was addressing the usb stick. It was the only "drive" containing an msdos partition.


As I did a set root first I'm pretty confident the '/ is as good as ($root) . I used command completion in grub to address Bootx64.efi via that path.

About the EFI boot setup on the usb I'm not so sure, but since the partition begins with /efi/boot I suppose it does. It's a Devuan live usb stick.

Does your PC boot EFI?  There is infrastructure that the boot image may need that might not be provided on an older PC.  (which could also explain why the stick doesn't boot.)
